# Bash glob parameter only shows first file instead of all files

Tags: bash, shell, glob

I want to run this cmd line script

```
$ script.sh   lib/* ../test_git_thing
```

I want it to process all the files in the /lib folder.

```
FILES=$1
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
done
```

Currently it only prints the first file. If I use $@, it gives me all the files, but also the last param which I don't want. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you're going to downvote, a comment explaining why would be very useful...

Comment: Don't do this: `SOURCE_FILES="${@:2}"; for FILE in $SOURCE_FILES; do`. That won't work if there is whitespace or glob characters in any filename. You don't need the temporary variable, so you could just write: `for file in "${@:2}"; do`. If you really want a temporary, use an array instead of a simple variable: `source_files=("${@:2}"); for file in "${source_files[@]}"; do`

Comment: Please add your own answer as a separate answer, not an edit to the question -- that way your question can be upvoted/downvoted/&c. separately from your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash and ksh you can iterate through all arguments except the last like this:

```
for f in "${@:1:$#-1}"; do
  echo "$f"
done
```

In zsh, you can do something similar:

```
for f in $@[1,${#}-1]; do
  echo "$f"
done
```

`$#` is the number of arguments and `${@:start:length}` is substring/subsequence notation in bash and ksh, while `$@[start,end]` is subsequence in zsh. In all cases, the subscript expressions are evaluated as arithmetic expressions, which is why `$#-1` works. (In zsh, you need `${#}-1` because `$#-` is interpreted as "the length of `$-`".)

In all three shells, you can use the `${x:start:length}` syntax with a scalar variable, to extract a substring; in bash and ksh, you can use `${a[@]:start:length}` with an array to extract a subsequence of values.

Comment: Accepting this one since it helped get to the best solution. I wound up changing the order, and simply ignoring the first param, then using the remaining params as a file array. Worked great! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The argument list is being expanded at the command line when you invoke "script.sh lib/*" your script is being called with all the files in lib/ as args.  Since you only reference $1 in your script, it's only printing the first file.  You need to escape the wildcard on the command line so it's passed to your script to perform the globbing.

Comment: Would another option be to either ignore the last Param or put quotes around the glob param?

Comment: Upvote for explaining that the glob was expanding. Understanding that really helped.

Answer (score 3):

As correctly noted, `lib/*` on the command line is being expanded into all files in `lib`. To prevent expansion, you have 2 options. (1) quote your input:

```
$ script.sh 'lib/*' ../test_git_thing
```

Or (2), turn file globbing off. However, the option `set -f` will disable pathname expansion within the shell, but it will disable all pathname expansion (setting it within the script doesn't help as expansion is done by the shell before passing arguments to your script).  In your case, it is probably better to quote the input or pass the first arguments as a directory name, and add the expansion in the script:

```
DIR=$1
for f in "$DIR"/*
```

Comment: `set -f` disables globbing; `nullglob` is the shell option to ignore a non-matching pattern, rather than treat it as a literal string.

Comment: Correct you are. Thank you for the catch.

Comment: @chepner `set -f` though suffers from the same limitation as turning globbing off with respect the instant script, it disables all pathname expansion if invoked rather than on a script-by-script basis. Sure would be easier the other way around...

Answer (score 0):

This answers the question as given, without using non-POSIX features, and without workarounds such as disabling globbing.

You can find the last argument using a loop, and then exclude that when processing the list of files.  In this example, `$d` is the directory name, while `$f` has the same meaning as in the original answer:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# != 0 ]
then
        for d in "$@"; do :; done
        if [ -d "$d" ]
        then
                for f in "$@"
                do
                        if [ "x$f" != "x$d" ]
                        then
                                echo "Processing $f file..."
                        fi
                done
        fi
fi
```

Additionally, it would be a good idea to also test if `"$f"` is a file, since it is common for shells to pass the wildcard character through the argument list if no match is found.